# Python Selenium Div Popup not found

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to upgrade my selenium skills. I am finding it difficult to find an answer for this question.

On the following page: [www.omegle.com](https://www.omegle.com)

When I click with selenium on the <kbd>Text</kbd> Button, it works with no issues. However when I try to access the "conditionals & Terms" window and try to click on the checkboxes, the Python/Selenium script fails.

[image: Here the example]

I don't understand it, well its a normal div without an `iframe`

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

#Intro
driver.get("https://www.omegle.com")
sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="textbtn"]').click()
sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div/p[1]/label/input').click()
sleep(5)
```

I even tried

```
driver.switch_to.frame(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the working code below:
You have to apply `waits` before clicking on the checkboxes.

Also, I refactored your code by using relative XPaths.

```
driver.get("https://www.omegle.com")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='textbtn']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//p//input)[1]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//p//input)[2]"))).click()
sleep(50)
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

**Result:**

[image]